# Python/Selenium web Scraping JS table without using JSON data

Tags: python, ajax, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape the table from:

https://www2.sgx.com/securities/annual-reports-financial-statements

I understand this is possible by studying the headers and finding the API calls such as this:
https://api.sgx.com/financialreports/v1.0?pagestart=3&pagesize=250&params=id,companyName,documentDate,securityName,title,url
but I was wondering if it is possible to get all the data from the table without doing so, as I would need to parse 16 JSON files.

When trying to scrape with Selenium, I can only get to the end of the visible table (the table gets much bigger when clicking "Clear all" on the left side, this is all the data I need).

Any ideas welcome!

EDIT: Here is the code, which only returns 144 cells from the thousands in the table

```
from time import sleep  # to wait for stuff to finish.
from selenium import webdriver  # to interact with our site.
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException  #  url is wrong
from webdriver_manager import chrome  # to install and find the chromedriver executable


BASE_URL = 'https://www2.sgx.com/securities/annual-reports-financial-statements'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome.ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()

try:
    driver.get(BASE_URL)
except WebDriverException:
    print("Url given is not working, please try again.")
    exit()

# clicking away pop-up
sleep(5)
header = driver.find_element_by_id("website-header")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", header)

# clicking the clear all button, to clear the calendar
sleep(2)
clear_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div[1]/article/template-base/div/div/sgx-widgets-wrapper/widget-filter-listing/widget-filter-listing-financial-reports/section[2]/div[1]/sgx-filter/sgx-form/div[2]/span[2]')
clear_field.click()

# clicking to select only Annual Reports
sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[1]/article/template-base/div/div/sgx-widgets-wrapper/widget-filter-listing/widget-filter-listing-financial-reports/section[2]/div[1]/sgx-filter/sgx-form/div[1]/div[1]/sgx-input-select/label/span[2]/input").click()
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Annual Report']").click()

rows = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("sgx-table-cell")
print(len(rows))
```

Comment: Select all of the sgx-table-cell classes and get the data in the tags as list. Then you can build the dataframe using the list. Without any code this is the best I can do.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to do so, but I can only get the elements that are visible on the page. Sending the browser the PageDown key does not work, as this has no effect on the table.

Comment: What have you tried? It is hard to understand why something is not working if we cannot see what you have tried so far. Please post your script.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: Just edited my question and added sample code, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

I know you have asked not to use the API. I think using it is **much cleaner** approach.

(The output is 3709 documents)

```
import requests

URL_TEMPLATE = 'https://api.sgx.com/financialreports/v1.0?pagestart={}&pagesize=250&params=id%2CcompanyName%2CdocumentDate%2CsecurityName%2Ctitle%2Curl'

NUM_OF_PAGES = 16
data = []
for page_num in range(1, NUM_OF_PAGES):
    r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE.format(page_num))
    if r.status_code == 200:
        data.extend(r.json()['data'])
print('we have {} documents'.format(len(data)))
for doc in data:
    print(doc)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have already written code for this, but I was hoping to find a solution using Selenium as well. Out of curiosity mostly! :)

Comment: Using API or scraping? With API you have ~ 10 lines of code. How many lines you have with scraping? With scraping your code will be broken as soon as anything in the markup is changed. Example: the class `sgx-table-cell` was renamed.